# Starting a new project with sbt-idea plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-idea

I am new to sbt and the sbt-idea plugin. I created a new project with the plugin and when opening the generated .idea file inside IntelliJ and compiling I am getting that "please specify compiler in Scala facet". When looking on the scala compiler facet all I see is  "buildScala" in red.

Since I saw many here are using the plugin, can you explain the steps you took to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this problem when I use the `sbt-idea` processor, and then import the *module* into an existing IDEA project. However, when I open the *project* created by `sbt-idea` I do not have the problem.

I have not been able to fix the red `buildScala` problem with imported modules. I suspect it would require tomfoolery in the project files, as I can't find config options to correct it via the GUI.

Personally, I always install [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) as a processor in every new SBT install I make. (See "Usage as processor" in the previous link). Then the correct way to generate project files is simply `sbt idea`.

Can you clarify exactly the steps you followed that led to the error?

Comment: +1 For the processor stuff. The first time I used it, I went through all the instructions on setting it up as plug-in, only to see that there was a processor available as well. I was disgruntled, to say the least. :-)